# floating elements on non-floated element:

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout, one of them is floated left, another is not:

```
<div id="left">
    LEFT
</div>

<div id="right">
    RIGHT
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}

#right {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: orange;
}
```

In the `right` element that is not floated, I have a markup like this:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="item">LINK</div>
        <div class="item">LINK</div>
        <div class="item">LINK</div>
        <div class="item">LINK</div>
        <div class="item">LINK</div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <h1>Welcome World</h1>
```

And the CSS for `nav` and `item` is (as you see, the `item` is floated):

```
#nav {
    background: blue;
}

.item {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

And my `clear` element is:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

And, at last, I get this result:

[image]

I think that the problem is with my `clear` element which is **clearing** the floated element too (`#left`).
But I expected to get this result:

[image]

[**Here is the fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/)

Comment: +1 for the fiddle. I always have to create one on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding unneeded mark-up in your HTML, you can just add `overflow: hidden;` to `#nav`. This will create a new block-formatting context for the list-items within `#nav`, as floated elements are taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) (its in-flow container won't respect their height, notice the `<body>` not extending down to `#left` in my fiddle)

From the [Visual Formatting Model, 9.4.1:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and **block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible'** (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

```
#nav {
background: blue;
overflow: hidden; /* Creates a new block-formatting context
                     for floated descendants */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/9/

Comment: **+1** for this nice solution `;)`.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/1/)**

Make your `#nav` element to `inline-block` and set the `width` to `100%`:

```
#nav {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a different way. You can move the clear to one of two different places (which gets you different results), but the overall problem is solved. Pick whichever one is more suitable.

(http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/4/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/6/)

In both cases I basically change nav's css (because no background would show otherwise)

```
#nav {
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'd just move the clear to the element containing both `div#left` and `div#right`. Putting it inside `div#right` seems to be creating some interesting effects with regards to the height of `div#right`.

Comment: Its iteresting what the clear does. If you put it above the H1 or below the H1 you get different results. Time to go lookup what `clear: both` is officially supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

[**Example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/7/)

Removed from #nav

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Added style to #nav

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Clearing floats are concerned with floated elements but you have cleared the element that you have not floated either left or right i.e. `#nav`. So add `float: left;` to your `#nav` then only your `<div class="clear"></div>` will work as what you want.

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJFUj/8/)**